# Site won't deploy hugo-academic theme created using blogdown

Tags: netlify, blogdown

I am trying to deploy the hugo-academic theme using blogdown with netlify. To deploy the site, I have:

1. Created an empty project
2. Created a new site with blogdown::new_site(theme = "gcushen/hugo-academic")
3. Dragged and dropped the folder into netlify.

No modifications were made to the site after it was downloaded from gcushen/hugo-academic

Although the site can be served locally via R-Studio, it doesn't deploy in netlify (page not found error). On the contrary, when I used the [One-click install of Academic](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/install/), I am able to deploy the site sucessfully. However, the deployed folder does not run locally on my machine with blogdown because of the following error

```
Could not find config.toml / config.yaml
```

As I am new to blogdown and netlify, I was wondering if anyone encountered the same issue and could offer some advice to have the hugo-academic site created using blogdown deployed on Netlify as suggested in the [step by step guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/netlify.html).

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Just wondering: Can I assume that you built the site once you created it (and then copied the resulting public files to Netlify)?